# I have a couple JComboBoxes in a JFrame that are slowing down a custom drawing JPanel under very specific cases. Does anyone know why this happens?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I'm writing a map making tool for a project that I am working on and I recently put in a JComboBox as a drop down selector for types of textures that can be applied to a tile. I'm custom drawing on an extended JPanel (labeled as DrawPanel) by overriding paintComponent() and calling repaint() for the graphical part of the editor and I'm also using various Swing components for the menus. Recently I started to notice that clicking on and opening the JComboBox caused the performance of the DrawPanel to slow to a crawl. I narrowed down the problem a little bit and figured out that it only happens under certain use cases (will explain them later). When the draw canvas is slowed down it can only be fixed by closing the window and re-launching or sometimes it happens intermittently when you resize the window. I suspect this works because the components get resized and re-validated but manually calling revalidate() didn't seem to work.

While looking into what exactly was being slowed down I put in some time measurments. I found that everything in the logic loop, i.e. update() and window.repaint(), all fire like normal: 10ms for the update method and as fast as possible with a 1ms sleep for the repaint() calls. When I timed inside of the paintComponent() method however I found that the time between the start of the method and next start of the same method had increased from an average of 1ms to an average of 30—180ms depending on how large the window was. The time it took to complete the draw functions didn't change though. I looked into it a bit more and to my understanding calling repaint() on the component schedules with the AWT thread using an event to paint the component again, but it's ultimately up to the AWT thread when it wants to actually do the repaint. This is to keep it concurrent and is also the reason why it's not recommended to directly override the paint() or update() method of a component. I'm not the best with everything Swing so please correct me if I got that wrong.

With this understanding though It seems like something is causing the AWT thread to either slowdown or focus on something else and doesn't get around to repainting the canvas as fast as I'd like it to. From now on we will just refer to the over all issue as a slowdown.

On to the use cases. I found that there are a number of use cases with JComboBoxes in which the slowdown occurs. Under all circumstances it only happens when the JComboBox draws the drop down outside of the JFrame. It also only happens when the JComboBox is unable to fill the area around it, whether that be by setting setMaximumSize() directly or if it is limited in size indirectly (such as placing it in a JPanel and letting it size to the width and height of it's contents). Oddly enough if the maximum number of displayed rows exceeds 10 the slowdown does not occur even if displayed outside of the JFrame.

Here's a Test class that I cooked up to show the behavior I mentioned. Depending on your hardware it might be noticeable a lot or it might not be all that noticeable. I tried to give the graphics card at least a little work so as to show the slowdown when it occurs. I ran this on my rig with a Ryzen 3800x and an RTX 2070.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TestClass{

    public boolean running = true;
    public long tickRegulator, displayTimer;
    public long UPSFrameTimeMark, UPSFrameTime, FPSFrameTimeMark, FPSFrameTime, UPSDisplay, FPSDisplay;
    public JFrame window;
    public DrawPanel canvas;
    public float time = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args){new TestClass();}

    public TestClass()
    {
        initialize();
        logicLoop();
    }

    private void initialize()
    {
        //look and feel + defaulting the timings
        UPSFrameTimeMark = UPSFrameTime = FPSFrameTime = FPSFrameTimeMark = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try{UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());}
        catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

        //below is the frame setup
        window = new JFrame("Test Frame");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //DrawPanel extends JPanel and uses an overridden paintComponent() to draw
        canvas = new DrawPanel();
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        window.add(canvas, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        //below are all the use cases for the JComboBoxes
        int itemCount = 20;
        String[] options = new String[itemCount];
        for(int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++){options[i]=""+i;}

        //The first two JComboBoxes are tested in a toolbar
        JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar();
        toolBar.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        toolBar.setFloatable(false);
        window.getContentPane().add(toolBar, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        //bottom left - max size not set (filling available space) - causes no issue
        JComboBox mapTextureOptions = new JComboBox(options);
        mapTextureOptions.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        toolBar.add(mapTextureOptions);

        //bottom right - max size set to 15x15 (although only the height is respected) - causes issue
        JComboBox mapTextureOptions2 = new JComboBox(options);
        mapTextureOptions2.setForeground(Color.RED);
        mapTextureOptions2.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(15, 15));
        toolBar.add(mapTextureOptions2);

        //the second two JComboBoxes are tested in a JPanel
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        window.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //top left - max rows set to 11 + no max size is explicitly set - causes no issues
        JComboBox mapTextureOptions3 = new JComboBox(options);
        mapTextureOptions3.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
        mapTextureOptions3.setMaximumRowCount(11);
        panel.add(mapTextureOptions3);

        //top right - max rows set to 10 + no max size is explicitly set - causes issues
        JComboBox mapTextureOptions4 = new JComboBox(options);
        mapTextureOptions4.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        mapTextureOptions4.setMaximumRowCount(10);
        panel.add(mapTextureOptions4);

        window.pack();
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void logicLoop()
    {
        long timeMarker = System.currentTimeMillis();

        while(running){
            tickRegulator += (System.currentTimeMillis() - timeMarker);
            displayTimer += (System.currentTimeMillis() - timeMarker);
            timeMarker = System.currentTimeMillis();

            if(displayTimer > 100)
            {
                FPSDisplay = FPSFrameTime;
                UPSDisplay = UPSFrameTime;
                displayTimer = 0;
            }

            try{
                while(tickRegulator > 10)
                {
                    UPSFrameTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - UPSFrameTimeMark;
                    UPSFrameTimeMark = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    update();
                    tickRegulator-=10;
                }
                window.repaint();

            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try{Thread.sleep(1);}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }

    private void update()
    {
        time += 0.02f;
    }

    private void draw(Graphics2D g)
    {
        FPSFrameTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - FPSFrameTimeMark;
        FPSFrameTimeMark = System.currentTimeMillis();


        //draw background
        g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, window.getWidth(), window.getHeight());


        float zoom = 0.05f;

        for(int x = 0; x < Math.max((canvas.getWidth() * 1.2f) / zoom, 500); x += 100)
        {
            g.setColor(new Color(27, 255, 0, Math.round(80 * 0.8f)));
            if((x - (0 - (0 % 100))) % 1000 != 0)
            {
                g.setColor(new Color(0, 255, 80, Math.round(28 * 0.8f)));
            }
            if((x - (0 - (0 % 100))) % 10000 == 0)
            {
                g.setColor(new Color(27, 255, 0, Math.round(128 * 0.8f)));
            }
            g.drawLine(Math.round((x + (0 % 100)) * zoom), 0, Math.round((x + (0 % 100)) * zoom), canvas.getHeight());
        }
        for(int y = 0; y < Math.max((canvas.getHeight() * 1.2) / zoom, 500); y += 100)
        {
            g.setColor(new Color(27, 255, 0, Math.round(80 * 0.8f)));
            if((y - (0 - (0 % 100))) % 1000 != 0)
            {
                g.setColor(new Color(0, 255, 80, Math.round(28 * 0.8f)));
            }
            if((y - (0 - (0 % 100))) % 10000 == 0)
            {
                g.setColor(new Color(27, 255, 0, Math.round(128 * 0.8f)));
            }
            g.drawLine(0, Math.round((y + (0 % 100)) * zoom), canvas.getWidth(), Math.round((y + (0 % 100)) * zoom));
        }



        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval((int)(Math.cos(time) * (canvas.getWidth() / 2 - 25)) + canvas.getWidth() / 2 - 25,
                (int)(Math.sin(time) * (canvas.getHeight() / 2 - 25)) + canvas.getHeight() / 2 - 25,
                50, 50);

        g.drawString("UPS Frame Time: " + (UPSDisplay) + "ms", 5, 20);
        g.drawString("FPS Frame Time: " + (FPSDisplay) + "ms", 5, 35);
    }

    class DrawPanel extends JPanel
    {
        public DrawPanel() {
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            draw((Graphics2D) g);
        }
    }
}
```

This is all of the necessary code to get the problem to occur. The test program includes a moving sphere so it's easy visualize the slowdowns as well as the UPS timings and the FPS timings. Pay attention to the FPS timings when looking for the slowdown. The two JComboBoxes that are leftmost do not cause the slowdown and the two that are rightmost do.

[image]

As you can see the FPS timings are at 1ms here even though the JComboBox is displaying outside of the JFrame.

[image]

In this image the drop box that I set to be a maximum size of 15x15 pixels causes the slowdown to occur and the frame time jumps to 12ms. That doesn't seem like much but if I increase the window size to be the size of my monitor (2560x1080) it slows down to a whopping 70+ms (in this example due to the JPanel taking up half the window at that resolution it isn't that bad but with the normal program it makes the frame time jump to 180+ms; nearly 5fps).

I don't know if there's something I'm missing here. Whether this is due to behaviors in Swing that I don't know about or if I've stumbled across a bug. Either way it's slowing down my application like crazy and I need a fix. (For now I'm just setting the max row size above 10 because that seems to work). Does anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: Could not reproduce. According to the FPS label, I'm losing maybe a frame or two when messing with any of the dropdowns. The laptop I'm on at the moment is Win 10 Pro, 2.2-GHz Intel Core i7-8750H, Nvidia 1060 Max Q., 16 GB RAM. The only "problem" I ran into is that you're not using generics, but those are just warnings.

Comment: When I run the UPS stays constant around 10. The FPS varies from 15 to 45 as I maximize the frame. The FPS does not vary if a combo box is open or not. I use JDK 8 on Windows 7. The only suggestion I have is that instead of using `window.repaint()` you should be using `canvas.repaint()`. No need to repaint the entire window.

Comment: Thanks that's actually a good point. I haven't tried this on another computer, maybe it's hardware specific?